# Не могу понять, почему pywinauto.findwindows не может найти элемент GUI. Вылезает ошибка ElementNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui, pywin32, pywinauto

Не могу понять, почему pywinauto.findwindows не может найти элемент GUI. Вылезает ошибка **ElementNotFoundError.** Имя класса **QTextEdit** определил с помощью inspect.exe.

```
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'best_match': 'QTextEdit', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <win32_element_info.HwndElementInfo - 'MainWindow', Qt5151QWindowIcon, 10486706>, 'backend': 'win32'}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import pywinauto, time
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().start(cmd_line='Main.exe')
app = Application().connect(title='MainWindow')
app.MainWindow.QTextEdit.click_input()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что для Qt приложений надо использовать "uia" backend:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().start(cmd_line='Main.exe')
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title='MainWindow', timeout=5)
app.MainWindow.dump_tree() # to see all identifiers on the window
app.MainWindow.Edit1.click_input()
```

Видео лекция на русском с расшифровкой: https://habr.com/ru/company/yandex/blog/336476/